# How to make a Chat list like Facebook Messenger in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm making a Chat app in React Native, in my app I have a Flatlist to show a message. When user pull the list, it will get new data and add to list. But the list will be re-render and scroll to start item. Is there anyway to make it still get data but stay in current position, like Facebook Messenger ?
I'm using FlatList like this :

```
                    <FlatList
                        refreshControl={
                            <RefreshControl 
                                refreshing = {this.state.refreshing}
                                onRefresh = {this.addMessageToList}
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        ref="flatList"
                        style={{ flex: 1 }}
                        data={newList}
                        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                            return (
                                <ChatContentItems item={item} index={index} parentFlatList={this}>
                                </ChatContentItems>
                            );
                        }}>
                    </FlatList>
```

Comment: Do you mean lazy loading?

Comment: Yes how can I make it with flatlist ?

Comment: Does your API support pagination or are you going to split the array by yourself?

Comment: I do it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Use [onEndReached](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#onendreached) event to handle when user reached the end.

```
<FlatList
    data={this.state.latestData}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString() }
    renderItem={({item}) => <JobsListCell item={item}/>}
    onEndReached={this.loadMore.bind(this)} // add this
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.3} /> // and this. change according to your preference.
```

Since you have the full array with you, slice and append the next items to the latest array.

```
loadMore() {
  let { latestData, fetchedData, incrementingAmount } = this.state;
  if (latestData.length < fetchedData.length) {
    this.setState({
      latestData: [...latestData, ...fetchedData.slice(latestData.length, latestData.length + incrementingAmount)]
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great ! I need to load the data at the top of list, so I think I need to use **refreshControl** right ? And how can I append **fetchedData** to the beginning of **latestData** ?

Comment: I have tried to append it, but the list will be re-rendered and show at the first item. I mean how to make it fetch the data at the top but still stay at current position, like Facebook Messenger ?

Comment: Maybe something like **onStartReached** and data fetch at the top

Comment: You want the data to be added on the top? @EmBeCoRau There's nothing like `onStartReached` in FlatList [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#props) and you don't want the `refreshControl` unless you want to refresh the list.

Comment: Yes because I'm making an app chat, like Fb messenger, the chat history was show whenever user scroll to top of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrollToEnd](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoend)   or [scrollToItem](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#scrolltoindex) after your addMessageToList completes

Also,  ref strings are deprecated. You can use

```
   ref={ (flatList) => this.flatList = flatList }
```

Comment: Can you show me an example that I can apply lazy loading in **onRefresh**, I just a newbie.

Comment: In this particular scenario of chat list, solution by @lasitha should work better because the latest items are the bottom of the list. But if you want to load old chat items at the top , refreshControl is the way to do it but then you would not want to scroll back to end of the item. You can add something like loadPrevious and append the items at the top in that case